# File upload in webwork not working

Tags: struts2, webwork

While uploading file in `action` class I am getting null value for file property
and in console i am getting warning:

> Item is a file upload of 0 size, ignoring

So, any one can help me to upload file.

Comment: problem solved by the way thanks

Comment: Post and answer and accept it, then.